# app crashes when try to create new record on remote database mysql using volley

Tags: android, mysql, android-volley

I have created a simple android app which connect to Remote sql database.. the problem is when I click on register the application crash. please help me guys

```
package com.example.akshay.webservices;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/20/2015.
 */
import com.example.akshay.webservices.AppConfig;
import com.example.akshay.webservices.AppController;
import com.example.akshay.webservices.SQLiteHandler;
import com.example.akshay.webservices.SessionManager;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    registerUser(name, email, password);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     * */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                    if (!error) {
                        // User successfully stored in MySQL
                        // Now store the user in sqlite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch login activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                RegisterActivity.this,
                                LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {

                        // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                        // message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting params to register url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("tag", "register");
                params.put("name", name);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

AppController.java

```
package com.example.akshay.webservices;

import android.app.Application;

/**
 * Created by Akshay on 7/19/2015.
 */
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
07-20 20:27:07.195    8233-8233/? E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
07-20 20:27:07.195    8233-8233/? E/Zygote﹕ v2
07-20 20:27:07.195    8233-8233/? E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
07-20 20:27:18.355    8233-8233/com.example.akshay.webservices E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.akshay.webservices, PID: 8233
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.akshay.webservices.AppController.addToRequestQueue(com.android.volley.Request, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.akshay.webservices.RegisterActivity.registerUser(RegisterActivity.java:185)
            at com.example.akshay.webservices.RegisterActivity.access$300(RegisterActivity.java:32)
            at com.example.akshay.webservices.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:81)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

This is the logcat I am unable to understand what is happening. Please help..

Comment: AppController.getInstance() is returning a null object.

Comment: Can you add that method code?

Comment: Try changing it to 
static AppController getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
    mInstance = new AppController();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

also check that your AppController class is registered in your manifest
like:
<application
        android:name="com.you.yourapp.AppContrroller"

Comment: can you please write it as answer with proper indent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is happening cause AppController.getInstance() it's returning null,
you have to change your AppController.getInstance() method to be this way:

```
public static AppController getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new AppController;
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

also make sure that you are registering your app class in your manifest
you should have an attribute in your manifest app like this:

```
<application
        android:name="package.AppController"  <--------
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="xyz"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

"Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. **You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag**, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created. "

Comment: This class extends Application

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same issue and when i tried this solution it did not work finally i got a way out.

The problem why it is returning a null pointer is because the methods getInstance() and getRequestQueue() are returning nothing with respect to the context. To solve that follow this steps. As prerequisite ad the following global variable in under public class AppController extends Application private Context myContext.

STEP 1.
        Create a constructor that defines the context

```
public AppController(Context context){
    myContext = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
 }
```

STEP 2. Modify hyou getInstance() method to work within the context as follow:

```
public static synchronized AppController getInstance(Context context) {

        if(mInstance==null){
        mInstance = new AppController(context);
         }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

Step 3. 
    Finally modify the getRequestQueue() method to work within the context as follows

```
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(myContext.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
Finally got the calling class and call the methods from AppController.java with respect to the context of the activity or broadcaster.

AppController.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```